# What's the best data transformation to build a radar chart?

Tags: data-transformation, normalization

I need to build some radar charts using NBA players stats, but obviously if I don't use the statistics expressed as a percentage (like for example "3-Point Field Goal Percentage" or "Free Throw Percentage") I have data with very different scale.
What is the best way to normalize data to build radar charts?

For example, if I want to build a 6-dimension radar chart with:

PTS(points per game) - min: 0 ; max: 30.6

AST(assist per game) - min: 0 ; max: 10.8

TRB(total rebounds per game) - min: 0 ; max: 14.7

STL(steals per game) - min: 0 ; max: 2.3

BLK(blocks per game) - min: 0 ; max: 2.8

PF(personal fouls per game) - min: 0 ; max: 3.8

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell a priori without looking at the figures. Exploratory and graphical data analysis is an interactive process, where the "best-looking graph" is found through (sometimes) long trial-and-error work.

Comment: What is the radar chart intended to show??

Comment: @whuber the differences of the players based on the stats I put as dimensions of the radar